# table view cell selection color works after 0 cell but not first row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I changed the tableview cell selection color and it works well only from row 1 and beyond but row 0 "first"doesn't it shows the default light gray color .

Is the way I did wrong?

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)



    // Configure the cell...

    let colorView = UIView()
    let green = UIColor(red:0.31, green:0.62, blue:0.53, alpha:1.0)
    colorView.backgroundColor = green
    UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = colorView


        cell.textLabel?.text = "#" + books[indexPath.row]

        return cell
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you realise, that you change **all** cells appearance with this call `UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = colorView`? So, each time your table view asks for one cell, you create new view, call it `colorView` and replace the `selectedBackgroundView` for all previously created cells? You're doing it wong.

Move this

```
let colorView = UIView()
let green = UIColor(red:0.31, green:0.62, blue:0.53, alpha:1.0)
colorView.backgroundColor = green
UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = colorView
```

to your `viewDidLoad` method.

But, it is ok only if you need not just green colour for selected cell, but something more complicated.

Better do this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.selectedColor = UIColor(red:0.31, green:0.62, blue:0.53, alpha:1.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just wanna change the background color, you don't need to create a UIView and set background color to it. instead change the contentView background and it should be in the didSelectRow... method. not in cellForRow.. as that is for the table view to load every single cell

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let green = UIColor(red:0.31, green:0.62, blue:0.53, alpha:1.0)
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.contentView.backgroundColor = green 
}
```

Comment: As far, as I can understand, @marrioa needs to change selection colour

Comment: well I think in that case, he is using the wrong delegate method. It should be in didSelectRowAt... delegate method

Comment: It should work fine, but it is not right place to do it. All cell configuration should happen in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. All `selectRow` methods are for user interactions response - like adding/removing cells, transition to new controller or modify data